# Triennial reading cycle for guests

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, hachnasat-orchim-guests

On one Shabbos, to accommodate a large number of guests from  another shul who follow a triennial Torah reading cycle, can we revert to the triennial cycle reading for that one Shabbos?

Comment: I didn't know that anyone still follows that cycle

Comment: If you did so wouldn't you be missing out on your regular reading? If so, why do their needs come before yours?

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA.  A more interesting question would be whether a shul on the triennial cycle should/must do the full reading if the large number of guests are from a congregation that does so.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to specify which stream of Judaism is being discussed - Orthodox, Conservative, Liberal, Reform etc.

Comment: Leib, perhaps you can answer [another question](/q/50988).